# Slayer Exciter Health Hazards

Tags: rf, radiation

I recently made a slayer exciter which produces arcs about 1-2 inches long. It also makes any electronic device near it go mad (it froze my iphone 6S when I was recording the arcs). What radiation is being produced? Electric field, electromagnetic waves etc. If it can create high voltage on any metal object that comes near, surely it will do the same to human nerves?

Should I be concerned about using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time-varying current produces, in theory, a variable electromagnetic field (EM field). Whether or not this field will give rise to substantial EM radiation, i.e. EM waves propagating through space, heavily depends on various parameters of the source and its coupling to (i.e. interaction with) the nearby space.

Anyway, the more abrupt is the change of the current, the higher is the frequency of (the highest frequency component of) the EM field and the higher is the chance that whatever is connected to the source will act as an antenna, giving rise to substantial EM radiation.

An electric arc, such as yours, is a very complicated beast, from an EM point of view. Not only it is a powerful pulse of current (hence very rapidly varying from 0 amps to its max), but it breaks through air, ionizing it in the process.

From an electric safety standpoint an electric arc may be dangerous in itself: it may escape its intended trajectory (like a small lightning), and make flammable things catch fire. Even if it lands on things that are not flammable, e.g. metal surfaces, the ionized air it produces, which is highly conductive, might cause short circuits in other parts of nearby electrical systems (maybe producing other arcs!). This may lead, in unfortunate circumstances, to a cascade of other failures in nearby circuits and systems, which may have dangerous consequences.

Now let's get to the EM wave part.

As I said, a rapidly varying current pulse will generate a corresponding EM pulse (EMP), i.e. a short burst of EM waves propagating from the source, which will cover a very broad part of the spectrum. How wide is the part of the spectrum that will be covered (and how powerful the EMP will be) is not easily calculated, given the complexity of the phenomenon. Small sparks may disturb radio communication well into the hundreds of MHz range (ever heard short cracks in your FM radio receiver when you switched a light off? That was the EM pulse of the small electric arc that forms in the switch during switching.)

Another thing to consider is the *power* associated with the EMP, which depends on the entity of the current variation. A 1mA-carrying spark will deliver a much feeble pulse than a huge 10A arc produced by an electric welder!

The problem with EMPs, especially powerful ones, is that it is difficult to shield a circuit from them, because they are so broadband. Even a Faraday cage is not going to suffice, unless it is a ***completely closed*** box of highly conducting material (even a single small hole in the "cage" can let some radiated energy inside, if you are unlucky). And even if the cage were a completely closed box, sufficiently powerful EMPs could "force" some EM radiation inside (only if the box material were ideal, perfect conductor, this wouldn't happen, but that's theoretical). That's why even armored tanks must be tested against EM pulses from, say, a possible nuclear blast.

If the pulse is powerful enough, even a small fraction of its spectrum will have enough energy to damage sensible circuits if they are not shielded or protected from signals at those frequencies. Any little piece of metal (or conducting surface) inside a circuit could act as an antenna for that tiny part of the spectrum that happens to bypass the shielding of your equipment. Once captured by that "antenna", the EMP will induce currents (and voltages) in the circuit it has broken into. If the power of the EMP is big enough, the induced currents/voltages will be able to destroy something (or everything) in the device!

**EDIT** (To address a comment by the OP)

> ...if metal nearby can act as an antenna, our nerves can too or is that due to the skin effect caused by the frequency?

Efficient antennas need to be made from high-conductivity materials and/or must resonate with the frequencies they are intended to receive. The human body is not so good a conductor, after all. The EMP can interact with human body structures and part of its power will be dissipated inside it, hence causing a very little temperature rise (unless we are talking about EMPs generated by nuclear weapons, but in that case there are greater dangers for people other than the EMP).

Small arcs, even if rather powerful from an electric circuit POV, cannot radiate so much power as to endanger a human by simple temperature increase (remember the EMPs are short in time, and the energy transferred in that time is limited).

The direct interaction with human nerves is debatable. Human nerves don't work as metal wires, as someone believes. The conduction of the nervous impulses through the nervous system is electrochemical, thus a nerve is not going to resonate with the incoming EMP as a trace on a PCB might do. Therefore significant energy transfer between the pulse and the nervous system is unlikely, at least when talking about EMPs generated by arcs that have a relatively low power level.

Comment: Is it more dangerous than the radiation of a cellphone. I've heard that the lower the freq the less dangerous. It is <500KHz compared to a cellphone's, around 800-1900MHz and ac WiFi 5GHz?

Comment: Do you mean dangerous for humans?

Comment: yes, surely if metal nearby can act as an antenna, our nerves can too or is that due to the skin effect caused by the frequency?

Comment: @TG see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Those things, well any high voltage arc really, creates a lot of broadband radio interference. That's both electric and magnetic fields. It's basically an EM Pulse, or a whole series of them, which is why your I-Phone froze. You are lucky it did not fry it entirely.

Whether those emissions are safe is up for debate. Some folks would argue just standing under power lines is bad for your health.

However, if you have any implants, especially a pace-maker, I'd stay a LONG WAY AWAY from that thing.

BTW: If you are a serious experimenter with this sort of thing, you really want to be working inside some form of [Faraday Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Those EM pulses you are generating are likely playing havoc with your neighbors WiFi, cell-phone reception, AM-FM radio reception etc. Apart from being a good neighbor, you do not want the local radio standard police knocking on your door.

Comment: Surprisingly when I put an FM radio near it I get perfect reception, and there are no AM radio stations where I live. It does not affect my WiFi or cellular reception/signal quality. I just did a WiFi speed test with my phone and the speed was the same

Comment: @TG the trouble with EMI like this is it is very broad band. That means you may be fine on a particular radio station, but not on the next. there are also a lot of different bands used for different purposes. Without EMI testing, you can never know who and what you are interfering with. Early radio, Marconi et.al. were basically just transmitting by using a spark.